# Get geode REST API going with SSL

Tags: gemfire, geode

I've setup gemfire.properties to make the web component require SSL using `ssl-enabled-components=web` and setting up a keystore. The locator and server are starting ok and GFSH connects to the JMX manager. However, when I try and start the Swagger UI then I am getting `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`. It happens when the config is that `ssl-ciphers=` and `ssl-protocols=` or set to `any`...

So what's the required REST API cipher for Apache Geode? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to use TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 as a default and same error, I can't get the Swagger browser to work with SSL enabled Geode...

Comment: The answer is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA and this changes the error to ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR so what's the best protocol to use ?!

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using on the backend and which browser/OS for the frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with a basic cert created with the following:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias self -dname "CN=trusted" \
  -validity 3650 -keypass password -keystore ./trusted.keystore \
  -storepass password -storetype JKS
```

It failed in the way you describe. I recreated the cert and used a different key algorithm with `-keyalg EC` and then worked. I'll see if I can give a more detailed explanation at some point.

UPDATE:

I'm using Mac OS and my `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/java.security` file contains the following restriction for certificates:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
  DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224
```

With `-keyalg EC`, the generated certificate is signed with `SHA256withECDSA`, but without that option it is signed with `SHA1withDSA`, so not acceptable.

Comment: so it was the way to generate the cert... it has to be with `-keyalg EC` and https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/12/managing/security/ssl_example.html needs to be updated!

Comment: we now have a Comodo trusted SSL certificate signed with SHA256withRSA but this same error has recurred. The Geode is hosted on a Win 2012 server. We imported the cert into the keystore with '-keyalg EC' or '-keyalg RSA' and same errors as above...

Answer (score 0):

For the signed SSL certificate I had to go through [this process](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/297/0/how-do-i-export-as-a-pfx-file-my-certificate-and-private-key-from-apache) using openssl to generate a pfx file, and then [this process](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/711/0/pfxp12-to-jks-java-keystore) to import that pfx into the java keystore, with the `-keyalg EC` flag. The Swagger then works fine using HTTPS.