# Geode SSL causes JmxManagerLocatorResponse ClassCastException

Tags: gemfire, geode

If you set `ss-enabled-components` to `all` and then start the locator:

`gfsh>start locator --name=IsLocator --bind-address=#.#.#.# --port=10334 --properties-file=..\config\gemfire.properties --security-properties-file=..\confi
g\gfsecurity.properties --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-start=true --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager=true`

the locator starts fine. So I try to connect the GFSH to the locator with an SSL connection:

`gfsh>connect --locator=#.#.#.#[10334] --use-ssl
Please specify these SSL Configuration properties:
key-store: trusted.keystore
key-store-password: ********
trust-store: trusted.keystore
trust-store-password: ********
ciphers:
protocols:
Connecting to Locator at [host=#.#.#.#, port=10334] ..`

There is an error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to org.apache.geode.management.internal.JmxManagerLocatorResponse`

Also, the locator logs show the `Cluster configuration service start up completed successfully and is now running ....` info, but then come repeated errors, all like:

`[info 2017/09/22 14:35:10.213 BST IsLocator <locator request thread[3]> tid=0x58] Exception in processing request from #.#.#.#
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.net.SocketCreator.configureServerSSLSocket(SocketCreator.java:1011)
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpServer.lambda$processRequest$0(TcpServer.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

What is the locator trying to communicate with?

Comment: It's the same error even if the locator doesn't specify `--J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-start=true --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was to do with not having set `keyalg=EC` in the SSL certificate per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349116/get-geode-rest-api-going-with-ssl)